# TargetFrameworkAttribute definition

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I got an auto generated file that has the assembly attribute defined and I am trying to understand the contents.

```
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NetFramework, Version=v4.0", Frameworkdisplayname= "")]
```

MSDN defined Targetframeworkattribute as "Identifies the version of the .NET Framework that a particular assembly was compiled against."

My question is does this mean this assembly can only be used on machines that have 4.0 installed or does this mean it has been build using 4.0 toolset, i.e msbuild from 4.0?

I am thinking, its latter, but any clarifications are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is does this mean this assembly can only be used on machines that have 4.0 installed or does this mean it has been build using 4.0 toolset, i.e msbuild from 4.0?

This means this requires .NET 4 to be installed to execute.  It's targeting the .NET 4 libraries.

While it was obviously built with the .NET 4 toolset, this is unrelated.  You could target .NET 3.5 and still use the .NET 4 toolset, in which case the `TargetFrameworkAttribute` would reference 3.5.