# With which .NET-Framework was a DLL generated

Tags: .net, dll

it is possible to get the information with which *.NET Framework version* a **DLL** was generated?

Thanks

Comment: You need required CLR version to run the assembly or target framework version? You need to find it use of any tool or programatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TargetFrameworkAttribute definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262397/targetframeworkattribute-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (or other similar tools, such as JustDecompile, .NET Reflector, ILSpy) you can view the property of an assembly.

[image: You can see the framework version here]

Comment: Better to offer choice by mentioning other tools - JustDecompile, .NET Reflector, ILSpy.

Comment: @JasonEvans Actually you are right, just that dotPeek is the only thing that came to mind. Edited to reflect your comment, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This information is stored in the [TargetFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute.aspx) attribute of the assembly. You can read it with a tool like ILSpy, or by using reflection.